# Will Office 365 unified API provide access to SharePoint Online lists?

Tags: office365

Will the new Office 365 unified api provide access to SharePoint Online lists and lists' contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the goal of Office 365 unified API is to be the single API you need to use to access all data across Office 365. SharePoint lists are definitely on scope for that goal, that said, we do not have a timeline that we can share right now.